# Physical location of particular file from Visual Studio Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2013, solution-explorer

I have VS2013 project from my colleague. [Following article](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2015/12/path-to-file-in-visual-studio.aspx) explains how to find physical location of file which is shown inside solution explorer. The process is fair simple:

> just right-click on the file's editor tab and select "Open Containing
>   Folder."

The problem is that I do not have "Open Containing Folder" under my menu as it is shown on figure bellow:
[image]

I'm using MS VS Community 2013

**PS:**

I've tried Right click on the project or solution name (not on individual file names) and select "Open Folder in File Explorer" but in folder which explorer opened there are no files that I'm looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Properties window (F4) there is a `Full Path` property for each file:
[image: Full path]